# Google analytics Users calculation

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying mimic this chart in GA:

[image]

But I have noticed that when I dont add date in my code the numbers match but when I add date the numbers seem doubling up.

[image]

Code:

```
SELECT 

date,

COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS Users, 

-- New Users (metric)
COUNT(DISTINCT(
      CASE
        WHEN totals.newVisits = 1 THEN fullVisitorId
      ELSE
      NULL
    END)) AS New_Users,
    
-- Sessions (metric)
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))) AS Sessions, 

-- Bounces (metric)
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN totals.bounces = 1 THEN CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))
    ELSE
    NULL
  END
    ) AS Bounces,

  -- Transactions (metric)
COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) AS Transactions,
    
--Revenue (metric)
SUM(hits.transaction.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS Revenue
  

FROM
  `ABC-ca-web.123.ga_sessions_*`, Unnest(hits) hits
  
WHERE trafficSource.campaign LIKE '%ABC%' and date between '20200801' AND '20200831'
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if you count users by date in GA, which is the usual query operation.

You cannot sum users from different periods. For example, if user X has visited the site every day in a week, analyzing the entire period the number of users is 1, but if you analyze it day by day it is 1 on the first day, 1 on the second day, 1 the third day, etc ... because the same user was there every day. If you count the users by days the result is that you have 7 users, but in reality you have 1 user because it is the same user.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose when you add "date", you'll be also adding a group by "date" as well, without which the query will error out.

When you take the distinct count of users per day, a user can be included in multiple days grouping. But when you drop the "date" field, then that user is included only once.

That's why you see double, but it could be any number same or greater than when you don't add "date"